# Css for javafx.scene.text.Text

Tags: css, javafx

I want to change color and font size of content of `javafx.scene.text.Text` but couldn't seem to find the correct css. I used the following but there were no visible changes.

```
.text { 
 -fx-font-smoothing-type: lcd;
 -fx-fill: white;
 -fx-font-size: 11pt;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I change the color and size of  `javafx.scene.text.Text` using css?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The content CSS is not available for Text node in javafx. If you apply .text{} it will apply to all button text and others but not to the Text node which you required. 
 But, you can use style class in css and use the same in fxml as given below.

```
.text-id { 
 -fx-font-smoothing-type: lcd;
 -fx-fill: white;
 -fx-font-size: 11pt;
}
```

Then in FXML,

```
<Text layoutX="238.0" layoutY="141.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" styleClass="text-id" text="NEW TEXT" />
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: If I'm adding `Text` through code, how shall I add this styleClass?

Comment: Missing set of ().  Correct above is node.getStyleClass().add("text-id");

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [CSS reference guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text), `Text` doesn't have any default style classes. However, the CSS selector `Text` can be used:

```
Text { 
 -fx-font-smoothing-type: lcd;
 -fx-fill: white;
 -fx-font-size: 11pt;
}
```